# Read MANDARIN From Excel using JAVA POI api

Tags: java, unicode, apache-poi

I need to read MANDARIN language data from excel file to persist it in the database. But the Unicode characters are breaking. 
I am doing the below stuff.

```
 FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
    String str = null;
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        cell= CellUtil.translateUnicodeValues(cell);
        str = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
        System.out.println(str);
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        str = new Long((long) cell.getNumericCellValue())
            .toString();
        System.out.println(str);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("It's here");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating in what whay the `Unicode characters are breaking`?

Comment: Are you sure that System.out.println() is properly working for unicode characters? Often the JVM output isn't set for unicode, which confuses you into thinking POI is broken when it isn't...

Comment: Thanks everyOne the above program is working fine. I missed the stuff because Language support was not install on my PC. That's why Unicode characters broke in console output.